# Which VFS to use in "sqlite3_open_v2()" call with NaCl port for Sqlite to enable synchronized access from multiple Chrome tabs?

Tags: google-chrome, sqlite, google-nativeclient

I am using NaCl port of Sqlite in a Chrome(NaCl) plugin. I can open DB connection using "sqlite3_open_v2(filename, &pDB, SQLITE_OPEN_READWRITE | SQLITE_OPEN_CREATE, "unix-none")". But I want to use the locking facility of Sqlite to enable synchronized access of DB from multiple tabs of browser(each tab is different process).

Which VFS shall I use instead of "unix-none" to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

If the locking function of the native I/O API were available, you would be able to use the default VFS (e.g., "win32" or "unix").

If only basic file I/O is available, the only locking style that actually works would be "unix-dotfile".